# Transforming a Kumaraswamy distribution to a gamma distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, gamma-distribution

How do I transform a Kumaraswamy distribution into a gamma distribution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $q$ be the quantile function (inverse cdf) of the desired gamma with whatever parameters are required, and let $X \sim \text{Kumaraswamy}(a,b)$. Then (following the same general method given in part (ii) of Step 1 [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/136058/805)), we get that

$Y = q(1-(1-X^a)^b)$ has the required gamma distribution.

If you don't care which gamma it is, the exponential is an easy choice to use.